# conver letters to digits in R

Tags: r

I need to convert letters to numbers according to the US phone number logic, i.e if I receive the string "ADA" I want to receive an output of 232

another example - input "TOM-GERRY" , output 86643779

I tried to split the string and loop on it but it doesn't work as I expected, how can I improve it?

```
QWE<-function(s){
  k<-c((unlist(strsplit(s, ""))))
  p<-0
  phone<-as.numeric(...)
  for(i in 1:length(k))
  if (i=="A-C") 
    p<-2
else if (i=="D-F")
    p<-3
else  if (i=="G-I") 
    p<-4
    else if (i=="J-L") 
    p<-5
    else if (i=="M-O") 
  p<-6
  else if (i=="P-S") 
  p<-7
  else if (i=="T-V")
  p<-8
  else if (i=="W-Z") 
  p<-9
    phone <- append(phone, p)
  }
return(phone)
```

Comment: `setNames(rep(2:9, c(3,3,3,3,3,4,3,4)), LETTERS)[strsplit('TOMGERRY', '')[[1]]]`

Comment: @rawr, please post as answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
setNames(rep(2:9, c(3,3,3,3,3,4,3,4)), LETTERS)[strsplit('TOMGERRY', '')[[1]]]
# T O M G E R R Y 
# 8 6 6 4 3 7 7 9
```

You can do this in one line, but this is a very general approach that I use for many recoding tasks.

Start with your text, and get rid of everything that is not `A-Z` and split the string into individual letters.

```
(x <- gsub('[^A-Z]', '', 'TOM-GERRY'))
# [1] "TOMGERRY"

(y <- strsplit(x, '')[[1]])
# [1] "T" "O" "M" "G" "E" "R" "R" "Y"
```

Next set up a key. Like I said, this can be very general, you can have multiple values mapped to single or multiple values like we have here.

```
(key <- setNames(rep(2:9, c(3,3,3,3,3,4,3,4)), LETTERS))
# A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
# 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9 9
```

And apply the key (and `unname` if desired)

```
key[y]
# T O M G E R R Y 
# 8 6 6 4 3 7 7 9 

unname(key[y])
# [1] 8 6 6 4 3 7 7 9

paste(key[y], collapse = '')
# [1] "86643779"
```

And you can wrap this into a function to make it more useful

```
f <- function(..., names = TRUE, collapse = TRUE) {
  unname <- if (!names) unname else identity
  collapse <- if (collapse) function(x) paste(x, collapse = '') else identity
  y <- strsplit(gsub('[^A-Z]', '', c(...), ignore.case = TRUE), '')
  key <- setNames(rep(2:9, c(3,3,3,3,3,4,3,4)), LETTERS)
  lapply(y, function(x) collapse(unname(key[toupper(x)])))
}

f('TOM-GERRY', 'tomgerry', '(tom) and-gerry')
# [[1]]
# [1] "86643779"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "86643779"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "86626343779"

f('TOM-GERRY', 'tomgerry', '(tom) and-gerry', collapse = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# T O M G E R R Y 
# 8 6 6 4 3 7 7 9 
# 
# [[2]]
# T O M G E R R Y 
# 8 6 6 4 3 7 7 9 
# 
# [[3]]
# T O M A N D G E R R Y 
# 8 6 6 2 6 3 4 3 7 7 9
```

Answer (score 0):

probably easiest way is to use mapValues() in plyr package. You should be able to create 2 vars one stage and the other the corresponding stage_number and parse them to the function directly.

```
mapvalues(str, from = c("beta", "gamma"), to = c("two", "three"))
```